# How to display concatenated value in MS Access Combobox

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox, concatenation

I'm trying to fill the combobox with values from a concatenated field in a MS Access query.  The embedded image is what is currently shown in the drop down box and what is shown in the box when a value is selected.

The problem is that i do NOT want the values in the drop down box to show as if in columns, but rather as a concatenated string.  So, instead of ... TAYLOR  |  AVICHAI ... it should be TAYLOR, AVICHAI.  And additionally, when the value is selected, then instead of showing just TAYLOR it would show TAYLOR, AVICHAI.

I've tried every property I can think of and tried concatenating in the original table, the query and even in vba code AFTER just grabbing the two fields from the database.

Any help?  [Concatenated View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2psH1.png)

Answer (score 2):

You need to concatenate the values together in your query and display that field in the combo box.

```
SELECT peopleID, lastName & ", " & firstName AS name FROM tblPeople
```

And then in your the format tab of your combobox set:

- column count to `2`
- column widths to `0";1"`

This will cause only your column with a width (the combined names) to be displayed in the drop down and when selected.

Comment: Thank you.  This didn't fix the problem exactly.  My code fills the combobox by looping... `Do Until rs.EOF me.combobox.value = rs!FullName ... rs.movenext ` ... where FullName is a concatenated field in the qry rs.  I think this is the problem...  i will have to fill the list using tables instead.

Comment: Could you please post your full code that is populating the list box?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says: "*[In a combo box, the first visible column is displayed in the text box portion of the control.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834480.aspx)*"

More precisely, the value shown is the value of *the first column with a non-zero width*.

Thus, to achieve your goal, modify your query so that it returns the following:

```
Taylor, Avichai  | Taylor | Avichai
Raines, Patricia | Raines | Patricia
...
```

Then, in the combox box properties, set

- the number of columns to 3 and
- the column widths such that the first column is *very* small (but not zero).

Comment: Thank you.  This makes a lot of sense, but didn't seem to work in my case...  My code fills the combobox by looping... `Do Until rs.EOF me.combobox.value = rs!FullName ... rs.movenext ` ... where FullName is a concatenated field in the qry rs.  I think this is the problem...  i will have to fill the list using tables instead.